# wxpython is there any way to change the textcolor according to if statements?

Tags: wxpython

How can I format the text in the self.verify box according to the conditions entered in the onsend function where if the first condition is met (the answer is true) the text in the self.verify box is written in blue, and if the second condition is met the text is written in red?
Are there additional values ​​in self.verify.write that can be used for this purpose or what?
Code:

```
import wx
import winsound

enletters= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

class lten(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, school):
        super(lten,self).__init__(parent,-1, title= 'Education system, english letters')
        self.p = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        self.Center()
        self.lettern= (0)
        self.letter= (enletters[self.lettern])
        wx.StaticText(self.p, -1, "answers: ")
        self.verify = wx.TextCtrl(self.p, -1, style=wx.TE_READONLY+wx.TE_MULTILINE+wx.HSCROLL)

        self.wt= wx.StaticText(self.p, -1, f"type  {self.letter}  ")
        self.write = wx.TextCtrl(self.p, -1)
        self.write.SetFocus()

        self.send= wx.Button(self.p, -1, "Submit the answer")
        self.send.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onsend)

        self.Show()

    def onsend(self, event):
        self.result= self.write.GetValue()
        if self.result == self.letter:
            self.verify.write(f'''true {self.letter}
''')
            winsound.PlaySound('data\\yes.wav', 1)
            if self.lettern == 25:
                self.lettern= (0)
            else:
                self.lettern= self.lettern+1

            self.letter= (enletters[self.lettern])
            self.wt.SetLabel(f"type {self.letter} ")
            self.write.SetFocus()
            self.write.SetValue("")

        elif self.result != self.letter:
            self.verify.write(f'''no
''')
            winsound.PlaySound('data\\no.wav', 1)
            self.write.SetFocus()
            self.write.SetValue("")

app = wx.App()
lten(None, None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by varying the text attributes `wx.TextAttr` using the textctrl's `SetDefaultStyle`.

Here I've varied the colour selection.

```
import wx

class Quote(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1)
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        self.text=wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(20,20), size=(250,220),
            style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.text.write('"Have more than')
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.BLUE))
        self.text.write(" thou ")
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.NullColour))
        self.text.write('showest,\n\nSpeak less than')
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.RED))
        self.text.write(" thou ")
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.NullColour))
        self.text.write('knowest,\n\nLend less than')
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr('#0000ff'))
        self.text.write(" thou ")
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.NullColour))
        self.text.write('owest,\n\nRide more than')
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr('dark green'))
        self.text.write(" thou ")
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.NullColour))
        self.text.write('goest,\n\nLearn more than')
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.Colour(0,0,255)))
        self.text.write(" thou ")
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.NullColour))
        self.text.write('trowest,\n\nSet less than')
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr('violet'))
        self.text.write(" thou ")
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.NullColour))
        self.text.write('throwest."\n\n-The Fool in King Lear Act 1, Scene 4')

        self.SetSize((300,300))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

def main():
    app=wx.App()
    Quote()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't worked with me, don't know why.

Comment: @ibraheemmohsen Then I shall assume that your cross-post at https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-textcolor-according-to-if-statements/36374 did work, unless you tell me different. The code above was tested on Linux wxPython 4.2.0

Comment: I wrote thank you in wxpython before I tried, and I did not edit it.
I am using windows10.